# How to delete a value inside of an array in a firestore doc

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Have been trying to figure this out for a while to no avail. My file structure is as so:

[image: file structure]

Basically, I am trying to create a function that takes a meetingID and AtendeeID, then looks up the document with the corresponding meetingID and deletes the specified attendee from the attendees array in the doc.

I have been playing around with `FirebaseFirestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove` but am not sure how to adapt it to my situation properly. Any help would be appreciated

For reference, this is where I am currently at:

```
const removeAttendee = async (meetingID, attendee) => {
  const meetingRef = doc(db, "meetings", meetingID);
  await updateDoc(meetingRef, {
    "attendees": FirebaseFirestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove({"attendees": attendee});
  })
}
```

Error:

```
./firebase.js
Error: 
  x Expected ',', got ';'
     ,----
 224 | "attendees": FirebaseFirestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove({"attendees": attendee});
     :                                                                               ^
     `----

Caused by:
    0: failed to process input file
    1: Syntax Error
```

Comment: That code looks fine at first glance. If `meetingID` is `_n21...` and `attendee` is `yOcNR...` then the code should remove that value from the array. If that is not happening for you, I'd start by setting a breakpoint and running the code in a debugger to check the variables. Oh, and maybe even before that, check if there are any relevant error messages when `updateDoc` runs.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen getting the following error as it stands, not sure where the ',' is supposed to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is good, it's just a typo, as the error message suggests, you used a semi-colon in your update object, simply remove it and the code will work just fine!

```
await updateDoc(meetingRef, {
    "attendees": FirebaseFirestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove({"attendees": attendee}) // here, remove the `;` optionally you can add a coma instead 
  })
```

Welcome to SO and happy coding.

Comment: Ah I see, guess I was thinking too deep into it lol, thank you so much!